# Disable SSRS Report Subscription

Tags: c#, web-services, reporting-services, sqlclr

I have requirement to disable SSRS reports hosted on Report url based on last login  information captured in Sql table.
i am using CLr type proc but not sure where to include sql manipulation to sql tables - Does anyone has pointers on same

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL manipulation code is part of your SQLCLR method.

Have a look at this link: [Data Access from CLR Database Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/data-access/data-access-from-clr-database-objects?view=sql-server-2017).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Do not manipulate the tables in the ReportServer database directly. Instead, create a proxy class for the Webservice and use its objects and methods to manipulate the Reporting Services objects.

To learn about this, you can use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-web-service/net-framework/building-applications-using-the-web-service-and-the-net-framework?view=sql-server-2017) to start with.